# Derive the Simpon's Rule for numerical integration

Tags: numerical-methods

I think I'm over thinking this because I'm coming up blank.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the question:

Derive the Simpon's Rule for numerical integration in a interval $[x_{0}, x_{2}]$ $$\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{2}} f(x) dx = \frac{h}{3}(f_{0}+4f_{1}+f_{2}),$$ where $x_{i}=x_{0}+ih, f_{i}=f(x_{i}).$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* With 3 data points, one can interpolate a quadratic polynomial. Verify that Simpon's rule  is exact for quadratic polynomials.